# She is carving in the door

Tags: passive-voice

She is carving in the door. How to change it into passive voice? If I write it like this; the door is being carved. So, where the "in" is to be put.

Comment: You would simply leave it out. "Carving the door" and "Carving in the door" mean essentially the same thing, is that right? If there is a fine distinction to be made (that is lost on me at the moment), you could always add it to the end of the statement, thus: "The door is being carved in." However, I don't understand what that means. I would probably say, "The door is being carved upon [by the woman]."

Comment: This smells of idiom. Can you give a fuller sentence in context?

Comment: Might I suggest that to carve out a door is to free a whole door from a larger piece of wood, stone or whatever. By contrast, to carve in a door is to make a carving in an existing door. To carve a door would normally be this latter meaning, but would not entirely exclude the possibility of the former. But I am more inclined to interpret "carving in the door" or "carving on the door" or even "carving into the door" to mean unauthorized carving or scratching into the surface of the door, a form of vandalism and not an artistic endeavor to create some form of decoration.